# Excel File, import data from a MDF file using a query

Tags: microsoft-excel, query

I got a MDF file with data on it, and i got an excel file that needs to display certain data from that MDF file based on data it already has.

How can i connect the MDF file to the Excel sheet so that it can be queried?

Comment: first result on Google: https://www.systoolsgroup.com/updates/export-mdf-data-to-excel-file/

Comment: @PeterH need it to be done through a query with data present in Excel. so i need to IMPORT from Excel to MDF. not EXPORT from MDF to Excel.  (so pull, not push)

Comment: @A.bakker,, you will need SQL Server Management Studio, and use its Import feature better [Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) !